# Can we engage a Valve specifically for a Tomcat Web App

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, tomcat-valve

I have some web apps hosted in Tomcat container, Can we engage a Valve specifically for a webapp ? Please give me a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you put the valve directive into your context.xml as follows.

```
<Context path="/myapp" ...>
  ...
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="10.1.2.*"/>
</Context>
```

I found [this page](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/11/11/finer-point-apache-tomcat-valves) to be a good tutorial on writing your own valve.